# Unknown Host error when attempting to connect to connect to Eclipse plugin repository

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, host

I am running Ubuntu 9.10 and I'm attempting to install a plugin for Eclipse 3.5 from a repository that my company created. This worked in the past on this linux box and also works just fine on my laptop which has Windows XP installed.

The exact error message I'm getting in Eclipse is:

```
Unknown Host: <location of repository>

org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.core.ProvisionException
```

Any ideas what might be causing something that used to work not to work anymore?

Thanks!

EDIT: Also, it might be useful to know that I can connect to other eclipse plugin repositories fine; it seems that only my company's internal one is the problem.

Answer (score 7):

It is usually due to a proxy used by Eclipse where it shouldn't use it to access a local self-hosted repo.

Try to set the proxy to "Direct" (hence selecting no Proxy entries at all)

```
Preferences > General > Network Connections,
```

[image: http://ftp.ntua.gr/eclipse/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.5-200906111540/images/proxy-settings-ui.png]

(so switch from "Native" or "Manual" to "Direct")

Comment: this is the best one. Great keep it up :)

Answer (score 1):

Try other link. I got the same error while using link for "Paris, France - Europe". But than I tried with http://emonic.sourceforge.net/updatesite/nchc/site.xml "Tainan, Taiwan - Asia" and all worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sun-java6/+bug/486215

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. When I ran /sbin/sysctl net.ipv6.bindv6only I got net.ipv6.bindv6only=0 though, so I guess that isn't the problem.