# jcraft, eclipse sftp plugin documentation

Tags: eclipse, documentation, sftp

I installed jcraft, but don't know how to use. is there any documentation available?. I googled, checked their site with no help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THat should be related to this [Guide to FTP & WebDAV support](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/index.cgi/org.eclipse.team.ftp/doc-html/index.html?content-type=text/html&search=None&hideattic=1&revision=HEAD), which includes:

- [Introducing Target Management](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/index.cgi/org.eclipse.team.ftp/doc-html/intro.html?view=co)
- [Importing a remote directory into the workspace as a project](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/index.cgi/org.eclipse.team.ftp/doc-html/import_remote_dir.html?view=co)
- [Exporting a folder to a remote directory](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/index.cgi/org.eclipse.team.ftp/doc-html/export.html?view=co)
- [Synchronizing with the remote directory](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/index.cgi/org.eclipse.team.ftp/doc-html/synchronization.html?view=co)
- [FAQ](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/index.cgi/org.eclipse.team.ftp/doc-html/faq.html?view=co)

Comment: thanks for reply, but it is not working for me. It tries to synchronize with server and never ends. I give up. sic :(

Comment: @robert: sorry to read that. Is this some kind of network preference issue (a bit like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241675/unknown-host-error-when-attempting-to-connect-to-connect-to-eclipse-plugin-reposi/2242757#2242757) ?

Comment: i found that my server blocks, ssh connection but it allows sftp. Does this got anything to do with the synchronizing problem

Comment: @robert: it is possible, but I don't know jcraft enough to be sure. Does it block ssh because of a policy or simply because your public key hasn't been published on it?

Comment: the hosting guys block all ssh access. They gave only sftp access..